# reload ad position with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to rotate ads at my website without reloading whole website, so each 25 seconds should be loaded new banner. Third party javascript of ad network looks like `<script type=text/javascript src='http://adnetwork.tld/banner.js?id=55&user=200'></script>`. I can put this code everywhere at my website and in that position is banner loaded.

I am using `setTimeout(function, 25000);`, but I don't know if code below is the right way how to do it.

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("cont")[0];
container.innerHTML = "<script type=text/javascript src='http://adnetwork.tld/banner.js?id=55&user=200'></script>";

jQuery( "div.cont" ).replaceWith( "<div class='cont'><script type=text/javascript src='http://adnetwork.tld/banner.js?id=55&user=200'></script></div>" );
```

How can I reload this position via javascript after 25 seconds, so new banner is shown?

**UPDATE**: (example provided)

```
<div id="cont">
<script type=text/javascript src='http://adnetwork.tld/banner.js?id=55&user=200'></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `scriptTag.src = "linkYouWantForYourAd"`
You can get the script tag by giving it an id or a class name

Comment: so if I understand it good, I should edit it to <script id="ad" etc></script>, and then just call ad.src = "http://adnetwork.tld/banner.js?id=55&user=200", right?

Comment: document.getElementById("ad").src = ...Almost